# Why does sending a delete request trigger the get_queryset() Django method?

Tags: django, axios, django-queryset, http-delete

I am having trouble sending a `delete` request from `axios` to my Django backend. With `axios` I call `delete` in the following way for many of my models:

```
// DELETE DAY
export const deleteDay = (day_id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/days/${day_id}/`, tokenConfig(getState))
    ...
```

The value of `tokenConfig(getState)` is just:

```
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Token 032b2f569037f0125753ef8f67e7774d34a756646ae28cefd54eb1c54bd0b149"
    Content-type: "application/json"
  }
}
```

In my `api.py` file I have many `viewsets` which use my predefined `model` and `serializer` objects. The `viewset` that should catch this request is the `DayViewSet`. I followed a guide to create all of these `viewsets` and from what I could find online, it seems that the guide I used uses [`GenericAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) functions. For this reason I've been using functions like `perform_create`, `get_queryset`, etc.

I have been able to successfully call this `deleteDay` function, and it would just delete the instance of the object based on the `day_id` I gave it, but recently, after changing my `get_queryset` function, it seems that a strange issue has arisen. Now, when I call the `deleteDay` function, it calls my `get_queryset` function instead of whatever is normal. Here is the `DayViewSet` object:

```
class DayViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = DaySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        day_filter = self.request.GET.get("day_filter", None)

        if day_filter == 'last':
            all_queryset = Day.objects.all()
            ordered_all_queryset = all_queryset.order_by("-day_id")
            if ordered_all_queryset.count() == 0:
                return []
            else:
                return [ordered_all_queryset.first()]

        if day_filter == 'first':
            all_queryset = Day.objects.all()
            ordered_all_queryset = all_queryset.order_by("day_id")
            if ordered_all_queryset.count() == 0:
                return []
            else:
                return [ordered_all_queryset.first()]

        eventdefinitions = self.request.user.eventdefinitions.all()
        strictevents = StrictEvent.objects.filter(
            event_id__in=eventdefinitions)
        looseevents = LooseEvent.objects.filter(event_id__in=eventdefinitions)
        occurs_on_1s = occurs_on_1.objects.filter(event_id__in=strictevents)
        occurs_on_2s = occurs_on_2.objects.filter(event_id__in=looseevents)
        occurs_on_s = occurs_on_1s | occurs_on_2s
        queryset = Day.objects.filter(day_id__in=occurs_on_s)

        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

So the issue is that whenever I call the `deleteDay` function it always calls the `get_queryset` function in my `viewset` and I'm not sure why. I tried adding a `perform_destroy` function, hoping that it would overwrite the delete request, but it's not overwriting it. So I have two questions, why is the `get_queryset` function being triggered when I call a delete request, and what can I do to make it trigger the `perform_destroy` function (or something comparable) instead.

Comment: There is not much  we can do, if there are cascading deletes required. still the question and answers are informative. I had once wondered why should queryset.delete query use this much resource

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call delete method, we must know which object will be deleted.

So we will call default `get_object` method in modelviewset as default method.

And then `get_object` calls `get_queryset`.

Therefore if you don't want to call `get_queryset` in `get_object` method.

Just override `get_object` not to call `get_queryset`.

Read for more understanding:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L83

Answer (score 1):

This is intended !!!

`DeleteView` is a kind of *detail view* which requires to fetch the object to be deleted using the ***`get_object(...)`*** method. This ***`get_object(...)`*** will call the ***`get_queryset(...)`*** method to fetch which all objects are allowed to perform in a particular view.

In your case, you are overriding the *`get_queryset(...)`* method for *filtering purposes*. You should override the ***`filter_queryset(...)`*** method to aplly the filters.